# What is the name of this NetBeans Theme property?

Tags: netbeans-7

I am customizing a NetBeans themes to find set up the right colour balance for my eyes.
I would like to change the colour of the default PHP functions in the suggestion (auto-complete box) to something different as I find the dark blue is hard to read.

I haven't had much like finding the name of the property to do so.

To explain further. I know where to change the colours. I just can't find this particular one.

Tools > Options > Fonts & Colours.

I am using 7.4 nightly build version (2013-06-19_17-09-51/ that I got here: http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nightly/)

I have changed my look & feel and using Dark Metal theme for the Tool itself. 
(Tools > Options > Misc. > Windows (tab)

If I find the answer myself, I'll post it here.

Thanks!

edit: 
It seems like it's not actually the Fonts&Colour theme that sets the colour.
Changing the theme from my custom one to e.g. Desert theme doesnt change the colour of the auto-completion box. So I was looking at the wrong place... nevertheless, I would still like to change the default colour of the text depicted below.

If anyone knows how, please share! :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is a bug.
I asked about the same issue on the NetBeans forum and got a reply.
Please see here for details: 
http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=148808